# NullPointerException (Bluetooth)

Tags: java, android, исключения, bluetooth

Доброго времени суток.

Приложение вылетает с NullPointerException при попытке подключения к Bluetooth устройству (HC-05). Сопряжение с ним проходит нормально, но вот дальнейшее соединение (создание сокета и тд.) не выходит - метод **startClient(device)** в **onItemClick()**. Toast с содержимым объекта device нормально выводит его имя и адрес, но вот startClient() ругается (полный лог ниже):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.bttest.BluetoothConnectionService.startClient(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)' on a null object reference
```

Скорее всего я тупо напортачил в классе BluetoothConnectionSrvice, т.к. не имею должного опыта.

Заранее благодарю за помощь

**Код MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "BTCS";
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT      = 1;  // Включение BT
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION  = 4;  //Данные о местоположении

private Switch btSwitch;                    // Switch
private LinearLayout foundDeviceListFrame;  // Фрейм с найденными устройствами
private LinearLayout bondedDeviceListFrame; // Фрейм с сопряженными устройствами
private ListView bondedDeviceList;          // Список найденных устройств
private ListView foundDeviceList;           // Список сопряженных устройств
private Button btnStartSearch;              // Кнопка "Поиск"
private ProgressBar pbSearchProgress;       // Search Progress Bar

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;                     // Bluetooth адаптер смартфона
private BondedListAdapter bondedListAdapter;                   // Адаптер для сопряженных устройств
private FoundListAdapter foundListAdapter;                     // Адаптер для найденных устройств
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> foundBluetoothDevices;      // Массив найденных устройств
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> bondedBluetoothDevices;     // Массив сопряженных устройств
private MacAddressMask checkMacAddress;                        // Проверка МАС адресов

private TextView myDeviceInfo;        // Инфо об устройстве пользователя
private String myDeviceName;          // Имя устройства пользователя
private String myDeviceAddress;       // Адрес устройства пользователя

BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
private static final UUID USER_UUID = UUID.fromString("f1190e86-3bb8-433e-8de7-ef29d4cb252a");

private RelativeLayout ledControlFrame;  // Фрейм с управлением устройством
private Button ledControlBtnDisconnect;  // Кнопка Disconnect
private Switch ledControlSwitch;         // Включение/Отключение светодиода
private TextView ledControlTV;           // Текстовое поле для приема данных

@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btSwitch              = findViewById(R.id.switch_bt_on_off);      // Switch для вкл/выкл BT
    foundDeviceListFrame  = findViewById(R.id.found_device_list);     // Фрейм с найденными устройствами
    bondedDeviceListFrame = findViewById(R.id.bonded_device_list);    // Фрейм с сопряженными устройствами
    bondedDeviceList      = findViewById(R.id.lv_bt_devices_bonded);  // Список сопряженных устройств
    foundDeviceList       = findViewById(R.id.lv_bt_devices_found);   // Список найденных устройств
    btnStartSearch        = findViewById(R.id.btn_startSearch);       // Кнопка "Поиск"
    pbSearchProgress      = findViewById(R.id.pb_search_progress);    // Search Progress Bar

    myDeviceInfo = findViewById(R.id.tv_my_device_info);              // Инфо о моем устройстве

    ledControlFrame         = findViewById(R.id.led_control_frame);
    ledControlBtnDisconnect = findViewById(R.id.led_control_btn_disconnect);
    ledControlSwitch        = findViewById(R.id.led_control_switch);
    ledControlTV            = findViewById(R.id.led_control_tv);


    btSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);       // Включение BT
    bondedDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(this);   // Ячейка сопряженных устройств
    foundDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(this);    // Ячейка найденных устройств
    btnStartSearch.setOnClickListener(this);         // Поиск

    ledControlBtnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(this);  // Отключение
    ledControlSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); // Включение светодиода

    foundBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    bondedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    checkMacAddress = new MacAddressMask();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    IntentFilter searchFilter = new IntentFilter();
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    searchFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(searchReciever, searchFilter);

    IntentFilter btcsFilter = new IntentFilter();
    btcsFilter.addAction(BluetoothConnectionService.ACTION_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(BTCSReceiver, btcsFilter);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth не поддерживается устройством", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth not supported");
         finish();
     }

     if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is NOT enabled");
         Intent btOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(btOn, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
     }

     if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is enabled");
         getUserDeviceInfo();
         showDeviceList();
         btSwitch.setChecked(true);
         setBondedDeviceList();
     }

    foundBluetoothDevices.clear();                                                  // Очистка списка найденных устройств
    foundListAdapter = new FoundListAdapter(this, foundBluetoothDevices);   // Адаптер для найденных устройств
    foundDeviceList.setAdapter(foundListAdapter);                                   // Привязка адаптера

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(searchReciever);
    unregisterReceiver(BTCSReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(btnStartSearch)){
        startSearch();
    }
    else if (v.equals(ledControlBtnDisconnect)) {
        // TODO отключение от устройства;
    }
}

private void startSearch() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG, "Discovery cancelled");
    } else {
        accessLocationPermission();
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        Log.d(TAG, "Discovery started");
        foundBluetoothDevices.clear();
        foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    if (parent.equals(foundDeviceList)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = foundBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
        device.createBond();
            Log.d(TAG, "Bond created: " + device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
    if (parent.equals(bondedDeviceList)) {
        BluetoothDevice device = bondedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        if (device != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, device.getAddress() + "" + device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Line №197");
            mBluetoothConnection.startClient(device);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.equals(btSwitch)) {
        enableBt(isChecked);
        if (!isChecked) {
            hideDeviceList();
        }
    }
    else if (buttonView.equals(ledControlSwitch)) {
        // TODO включение светодтода
        mBluetoothConnection.write(isChecked);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            showDeviceList();
        }

        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            btSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

private void showDeviceList() {
    foundDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bondedDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ledControlFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
private void hideDeviceList() {
    foundDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    bondedDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ledControlFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void showLedControlFrame() {
    ledControlFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    foundDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    bondedDeviceListFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void getUserDeviceInfo() {
    myDeviceName    = bluetoothAdapter.getName();
    myDeviceAddress = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
    myDeviceInfo.setText(myDeviceName + "\n" + myDeviceAddress);
}

private void enableBt(boolean flag) {
    if (flag) {
        Intent btOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(btOn, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    else {
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }
}

 private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> getBondedBtDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> deviceSet = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> tmpArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (deviceSet.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device: deviceSet) {
            if (checkMacAddress.macAddressMask(device.getAddress())) {
                tmpArrayList.add(device);
                Log.d(TAG, "Got bonded device: " + device.getName() + " " + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
    return tmpArrayList;
 }

 private void setBondedDeviceList() {
    bondedBluetoothDevices.clear();
    showDeviceList();
    bondedBluetoothDevices = getBondedBtDevices();
    bondedListAdapter = new BondedListAdapter(this, bondedBluetoothDevices);  // Адаптер для сопряженных устройств
    bondedDeviceList.setAdapter(bondedListAdapter);                                   // Привязка адаптера
 }

private final BroadcastReceiver searchReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         String action = intent.getAction();

         switch (action) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
                btnStartSearch.setText("Остановить поиск");
                pbSearchProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showDeviceList();
                Log.d("searchReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED");
                break;

            case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
                 btnStartSearch.setText("Начать поиск");
                 pbSearchProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d("searchReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");
            break;

            case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
                 BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                 if (device != null && !foundBluetoothDevices.contains(device) && device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && checkMacAddress.macAddressMask(device.getAddress()) == true) {
                         foundBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                         foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     Log.d("searchReceiver", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND");
                 }
            break;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Слушатель состояния Bluetooth
 **/

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();

                if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                    final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                            BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                    switch (state) {
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                            btSwitch.setChecked(false);
                            Log.d("mReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OF");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                            // Turning Bluetooth off...
                            Log.d("mReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                            btSwitch.setChecked(true);
                            setBondedDeviceList();
                            showDeviceList();
                            getUserDeviceInfo();
                            Log.d("mReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                            Log.d("mReceiver", "BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                    setBondedDeviceList();
                    startSearch();
                    bondedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    foundListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

private BroadcastReceiver BTCSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothConnectionService.ACTION_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Типа соединяюсь с устройством", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "connectThread: run: Could not connect");
        }
        if (action.equals(BluetoothConnectionService.ACTION_SUCCESS)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_SUCCESS");
            showLedControlFrame();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION:

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int gr: grantResults) {
                    if (gr != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

/**
 *Запрос на разрешение получения данных о местоположении (6.0)
 **/
private void accessLocationPermission() {
    int accessCoarseLocation = this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int accessFineLocation   = this.checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    List<String> listRequestPermission = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (accessCoarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listRequestPermission.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (accessFineLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listRequestPermission.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (!listRequestPermission.isEmpty()) {
        String[] strRequestPermission = listRequestPermission.toArray(new String[listRequestPermission.size()]);
        this.requestPermissions(strRequestPermission, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
    }
}
}
```

**Код из класса BluetoothConnectionService:**

```
public class BluetoothConnectionService {

public static final String ACTION_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED = "Socket connection failed";
public static final String ACTION_SUCCESS              = "Device Connected";

private static final String TAG = "BTCS";

private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("f1190e86-3bb8-433e-8de7-ef29d4cb252a");
private UUID deviceUUID;
Context mContext;

private final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
private ConnectedThread connectedThread;

public BluetoothConnectionService(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
    private boolean success = false;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        //device = device;
        //deviceUUID = uuid;
        try {
            Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
            bluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket) method.invoke(device, 1);

//  Другой способ              Log.d(TAG, "ConnectThread: Trying to create RfcommSocket using UUID: " + USER_UUID);
//  (тоже ошибка)              bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ConnectThread: Could not create RfcommSocket " + e.getMessage());
            }
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "run: ConnectThread connected. ");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "run: Could not connect");
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED);
            intent.putExtra("Debug", "ConnectThread: run: Could not connect");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
            cancel();
        }

        if (success) {
            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
            connectedThread.start();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SUCCESS);
            intent.putExtra("success", "Device connected");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnect() {
        return bluetoothSocket.isConnected();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "cancel: Closing Client Socket. ");
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cancel: close() of bluetoothSocket in ConnectThread failed. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get streams " + e.getMessage());
        }

        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    public void write(String command) {
        byte[] bytes = command.getBytes();
        Log.d(TAG, "write: Writing to outputStream: " + bytes);
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "write: Error writing to output stream. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "run: close: Could not close streams");
        }
    }
}

public void write(boolean state) {
    if (connectedThread != null && connectThread.isConnect()) {
        String command = "";
        if (state) {
            command = "on#";
        }
        if (!state) {
            command = "off#";
        }
        connectedThread.write(command);
    }
}

public void startClient(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "startClient: Started. ");

    connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    connectThread.start();
}
}
```

**Логи:**

```
2020-08-13 12:30:53.085 8333-8333/com.example.bttest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bttest, PID: 8333
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.bttest.BluetoothConnectionService.startClient(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.bttest.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:197)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:374)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1736)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4207)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$7.run(AbsListView.java:6692)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: А где вы инициализируете mBluetoothConnection?

Comment: Так и есть, благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно ваша проблема в том, что вы нигде не ининциализируете ваш объект `BluetoothConnectionService`. А значит он `null`, о чем вам и говорит ошибка.

```
BluetoothConnectionService bluetoothConnectionService = new BluetoothConnectionService(context);
```

Должно решить вашу проблему

Comment: Боже, даже стыдно, на такой простой вещи сел. Спасибо. Теперь вроде как-то еще работает, но не до конца, но это уже совсем другая проблема. Сделал инициализацию сразу перед startClient()- это правильно? Или лучше ее проводить непосредственно в onCreate()?

Comment: Ну я думаю, что инициализировать нужно непосредственно перед первым местом вызова. Допустим вы можете в какой-то момент даже не дойти до использования вашего объекта, зачем тогда вы его будет создавать заранее если он ни разу не используется?

Comment: Так и думал, поэтому и вызываю перед созданием сокета. Спасибо. Теперь еще один вопрос: в чем отличие между созданием сокета через рефлексию (реализовано в ConnectThread) и между тем что ниже закомментировано. Я вижу разницу только в наличии/отсутствии UUID. Только вот создание через рефлексию работает, а напрямую нет.

Comment: UPD коммента выше. Реализовал с использованием UUID, хотя так и не допер зачем он нужен